# Rails distance_of_time_in_words with direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a Rails helper or ruby gem similar to `distance_of_time_in_words` that takes direction (future/past) into account?

This is how it works

```
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now 30.days.ago
# "about 1 month"
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now 30.days.from_now
# "about 1 month"
```

But I'd like to find something that works more like:

```
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now 30.days.ago
# "about 1 month ago"
distance_of_time_in_words_to_now 30.days.from_now
# "in about 1 month"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) there isn't.

But, this is trivial enough that you can wrap it in a simple method:

```
def distance_of_time(time)
  if time > Time.now
    "in #{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now time}"
  else
    "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now time} ago"
  end
end
```

Comment: The method should be called `time_in_words`, since we already have `time_ago_in_words`